# How to create a simple chat App in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, chat, livechat

last some days am searching for a chatApp. So anyone kindly help me to create simple chat app.I need to chat one to one and one to many , please refer some working samples or tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your friend.

Something like this ?

https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/minichat-ios-messaging-app/
https://github.com/relatedcode/RealtimeChat

Comment: I got this link in Google :)